# Linux cron job error

Tags: linux, cron, crontab

I have setup a cron job to run a PHP file every 30 minutes:

> lynx -source public_html/scripts/file.php

The result comes through to an email but seems to get this error:

> Can't Access
>   `file://localhost/home/username/public_html/scripts/file.php'
>   Alert!: Unable to access document.
>
> lynx: Can't access startfile

Comment: What is the job supposed to do ?
Does the job work  if you run it by hand (command line) ?

Comment: Lynx is a web browser, so it needs an uri for a web resource. But you could use php to run the script.

Answer (score 3):

Several things are wrong here.

First, before putting a command in crontab, check that it works by running it yourself.

Second, if you want the html code generated by a (dynamic) php webpage, you must access trough the web server, not reading the php from from the filesystem. In the case of a php webpage, an alternative (not necesarily equivalent) would be to just invoke the php interpreter from the CLI:

```
php public_html/scripts/file.php
```

Third, no need to you use lynx (a text browser) for that, go wget:

```
wget http://localhost/scripts/file.php
```

Perhaps you must change the url, that depends on your webserver configuration. Load it first in your web browser to check.